# Arrangement of people in a row

Tags: combinations

If six women and six men are to be seated in a row alternately , what is the number of possible arrangements ? 
According to the answer it’s should be $2(6!)^2$ however I just wanted to verify what is wrong with the approach that I chose ? 
First seat $6$ men in a row , leaving one seat between every two men vacant. Now there are $7$ seats for the women who can be arranged in ${{7}\choose{6}}6!$ ways. Hence men and women can together be arranged in $7!6!$ ways. Why am I not getting the answer with this ? Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is as follows:

Let $*$ denote the empty space

$$*M*M*M*M*M*M*$$

what if the women choose the following combination instead:

$$WMWMWM*MWMWMW$$

In stead, a quick correction is the women actually only has two choices, to remove the first seat (that is choosing to keep the last $6$ seats) or remove the last seat. They can then permute among themselves.

Comment: Okay ! I understand now . Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your attempt:

- it doesn't necessarily seat men and women alternately, e.g. $WM-MWMWMWMWMW$
- you had (originally) forgotten to permute the men, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Oh yes.. I understand now.. thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome !